# Do not send an email PHP

Tags: php

**Even the errors fields `fnameErr, lnameErr` are empty my code is still printing "Do not send an email"**

```
        // define variables and set to empty values
    $nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
    $name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
       if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
         $fnameErr = "First Name is required";
       } else {
         $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
         // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
         if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$fname)) {
           $fnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
         }
         $stop=true;
       }
       if (empty($_POST["lname"])) {
         $lnameErr = "Last Name is required";
       } else {
         $lname = test_input($_POST["lname"]);
         // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
         if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lname)) {
           $lnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
         }
          $stop=true;
       }
       if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
         $emailErr = "Email is required";
       } else {
         $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
         // check if e-mail address is well-formed
         if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
           $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
         }
           $stop=true;
       }

       if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
         $phoneErr = "Phone is required";
          $stop=true;
       }

       if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
          $commentErr = "Comments is required";
           $stop=true;
       }


        if(!$stop)

        {
             echo "send an email";
        }

    }

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
```

my HTML code

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
                                                <fieldset>
                                                  <h4>&nbsp;</h4>   
                                                    <div class="form-group"> 
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_POST["fname"];?>"><span class="error"><?php echo $fnameErr;?></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group"> 
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <input id="lname" name="lname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_POST["lname"];?>"><span class="error"><?php echo $lnameErr;?></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                        <div class="form-group"> 
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_POST["email"];?>"><span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="form-group"> 
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_POST["phone"];?>"><span class="error"><?php echo $phoneErr;?></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="form-group"> 
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <textarea class="form-control" id="comment" name="comment" placeholder="Enter your message" rows="7"><?php echo $_POST["comment"];?></textarea><span class="error"><?php echo $commentErr;?></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <div class="col-md-12 text-left">
                                                            <button type="submit"  name="submit" class="btn btn-primary readmmore">Submit</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </fieldset>
                                            </form>
```

Comment: This is all I can say: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- there is not error

Comment: When you debug this, what values are in those variables?

Comment: @David i updated the code so its $emailErr, $commentErr

Comment: @user580950: And how about the debugging results?  The logic of this code doesn't make much sense to me.  You want to send an email if any one field is without error?  But it's ok if other fields have errors?

Comment: @David The email should be sent if none of the fields are empty

Comment: @user580950: The input fields, or the variables that you're checking?  And now that you've completely changed the code in the question, how is it failing?  You need to actually run this code and debug it and observe its behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this(you were setting $stop to true in the wrong places):

```
        // define variables and set to empty values
    $nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
    $name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

    // Let's explicityly set $stop to false(some PHP settings require this)
    $stop = False;

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
       if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
         $fnameErr = "First Name is required";
         $stop=true;
       } else {
         $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
         // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
         if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$fname)) {
           $fnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
           $stop=true;
         }

       }
       if (empty($_POST["lname"])) {
         $lnameErr = "Last Name is required";
         $stop=true;
       } else {
         $lname = test_input($_POST["lname"]);
         // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
         if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lname)) {
           $lnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
           $stop=true;
         }
       }
       if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
         $emailErr = "Email is required";
         $stop=true;
       } else {
         $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
         // check if e-mail address is well-formed
         if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
           $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
           $stop=true;
         }
       }

       if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
         $phoneErr = "Phone is required";
         $stop=true;
       }

       if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
          $commentErr = "Comments is required";
          $stop=true;
       }


   if ($stop){
      // Validation failed, dont send email
   } else {
      // Validation passed, send email
   }    


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want only fNameErr and LnameErr to stop the send then you'll have to use:

```
if(empty($fnameErr) && empty(lnameErr) && empty(emailErr) && empty(phoneErr) && empty(commentErr))

    {

        echo "send an email";

    }
```

Comment: i want to send an email if all the fields are non empty

Comment: Yes, but you are checking for validity based on empty error variables.  An easier way to do this would be to set `$stop = True` wherever you have a error message set in the top portion of code, then check for `if (!$stop){ .. }` in your send email check.

Comment: @AndrewCoder so $stop = "True" ?

Comment: that is a great idea Andrew

Comment: Yes, set `$stop = True;` in your upper validity checks, when something is wrong.  Then the `if` logic when you want to e-mail is much simpler to understand.

Comment: No quotes on the True btw, use an actual boolean.

Comment: @AndrewCoder 
I tried that its not printing anything now   if(!$stop)

 {
         echo "send an email";
 }

and i have set that everywhere  $stop=true;